# Android: how to start setting activity with back button

Tags: android

When I start Wifi setting page from android's setting page, there is a back button in the top action bar. But there is not when I start Wifi setting from my own app.

The code I am using is:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

I know that the wifi setting activity and my activity are already in the same back stack. Is there any way to show the back button in the action bar?

Comment: try "startActivityForResult"

Comment: @HuyVo Thank you for response. I have already tried that. Still not work.

Comment: Tim OMalley's reply works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to do what you want. However, I think that even if there were, it is unlikely that you would actually want to do it.

The "back" button in the action bar is actually an **Up** button. Clicking it wouldn't take the user back to your app; it would take the user up one level within the device settings.

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity( intent);
```

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK achieves the desired result, this should be the accepted answer @ukim